# Create javascript variable from php template using <script> tag - PHP/Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, security, xss

I'd like to dynamically assign a JS variable from one of my php page-templates in order to use the assigned variable within my `bundle.js` file.

I'm doing this using this way:

*template-some-page.php:*

```
<?php
       echo "<script>
       var javascriptVar = 'success';
       </script>";
?>

<div>
  ...
</div>
```

*bundle.js:*

```
function readVar() {
   console.log(javascriptVar )
}
```

This approach works perfectly fine, but the question is it a good practice using this way?
Is creating a  tag within the body is safe ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have shown presents no security issue save one: it stuffs your `javascriptVar` into the [global Javascript object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object).

You might do better to use this.

```php
    echo "<script>
       var annasApp = annasApp || {};
       annasApp.javascriptVar = 'success';
       </script>";
```

The line `var annasApp = annasApp || {};` creates an object in the global namespace if it doesn't already exist. Then it assigns a property value to the object. This makes for a cleaner and less error-prone global namespace -- other code is less likely to step on your code and vice versa.

If your code wants to do `annasApp.javascriptVar = $phpVariable;` you *do have a potential security problem*. You *must* escape the data in $phpVariable before echoing it. If you don't, your code might be vulnerable to [cross-site scripting attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/). A good and safe way to handle that is using JSON.

```php
    $jsonVariable = json_encode( htmlspecialchars( $phpVariable ) );
    echo "<script>
       var annasApp = annasApp || {};
       annasApp.javascriptVar = $jsonVariable;
       </script>";
```

`htmlspecialchars()` is unnecessary unless your Javascript data will be rendered using HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What should  I do in case that the $phpVariable is of type array that i'd like to convert to JS array?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$script = "
 <script>
  console.log("Hello World");
  var javascriptVar = "success";   
 </script>";
echo $script; 
?>
```

(or)

you can close the PHP tag and write some Html or js script and re-open the PHP  tag to continue writing the remaining PHP code in the same .php extension file

```
<?php 
 // my PHP code
?>
<script>
  console.log("Hello World");
  var javascriptVar = "success";   
</script>
<?php 
 // my PHP code
?>
```